# Remember input values when toggle form

Tags: javascript, input, toggle

I have the following code https://jsfiddle.net/82dce8Lp/. This are 2 html forms and they can be switched on click.

I want to remember the input values if the form is switched.

```
$('.message a').click(function() {
  $('form').animate({
    height: "toggle",
    opacity: "toggle"
  }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Where you want to save those values?

Comment: My bad. I want to remember them, not to save them.

I mean if the user typed his username in login form and switch to register, so there have to be the username from the login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. :)

```js
let isSignIn = true;
$('.message a').click(function() {
  $('form').animate({
    height: "toggle",
    opacity: "toggle"
  }, "slow");
  transferInputData();
});

function transferInputData() {
  if(isSignIn) {
    $('#registerName').val($('#loginName').val());
    $('#registerPW').val($('#loginPW').val());    
  } else {
    $('#loginName').val($('#registerName').val());
    $('#loginPW').val($('#registerPW').val());
  }
  isSignIn = !isSignIn;
}
```

```css
.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form .btn {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form button:hover,
.form button:active,
.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}

.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}

.infoo {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.infoo h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.infoo span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.infoo span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.infoo span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="login_page" class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form id="register_form" class="register-form">
      <input id="registerName" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
      <input id="registerPW" type="password" placeholder="password" />
      <input id="registerEmail" type="text" placeholder="email address" />
      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign up" />
      <p class="message">
        Already registered?
        <a href="#">Sign In</a>
      </p>
    </form>
    <form id="login_form" action="#" method="POST" class="login-form">
      <input id="loginName" name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" />
      <input id="loginPW" name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
      <input id="btnLg" type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign in" />
      <p class="message">
        Not registered?
        <a href="#">Create an account</a>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```